# Which version of ZSH is installed in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, zsh

I am required to write a script on Linux while still supporting macOS. I am using ZSH. macOS Catalina has ZSH enabled by default, but the feature I am building has a version dependency on the ZSH version.

Which version of ZSH comes pre-installed with macOS catalina? (I did not have access to a macOS Catalina based machine at the time of writing this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the following commands in macOS Catalina 10.15:

```
sw_vers
```

> ProductName:  Mac OS X
>   ProductVersion:   10.15
>   BuildVersion: 19A602

```
zsh --version
```

> zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Comment: BTW MacOS 11.6 has zsh 5.8.